# get_search_form(wordpress) in a placeholder web form

Tags: php, html

I have made a placeholder web form:

```
<input type="text" value="Search" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search';}" >
```

Now I need to add the Wordpress get_search_form code in this to allow this form to search my website. Can you guys please help me out, on how to implement this?

Heres the search.php code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfWi0.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also a template file called searchform.php. This is a template file that is often included in the sidebar of many themes and generates the search box form. If there isn't one in your theme, you can easily copy it from the Default theme, Or the code below

```
    <form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
    <label for="s" class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Search' ); ?></label>
    <input type="text" name="s" id="s" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search' ); ?>" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search';}" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search' ); ?>" />
</form>
```